# AttributeError: module 'email.message' has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, flask

I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'email.message' has no attribute 'lower'` on my browser after performing action. There is no attribute lower() in my code. Please help me with this. Thank You.

I have following imports in my code
pandas, matplotlib, email.message and flask

```
df = pd.read_csv('spam.csv',encoding='latin-1')
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4'], axis = 1)

df.rename(columns = {'v1':'labels', 'v2':'message'}, inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df['label'] = df['labels'].map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})
df.drop(['labels'], axis=1, inplace=True)

import string

def preprocess_text(message):

    without_punc = [char for char in message if char not in string.punctuation]
    without_punc = ''.join(without_punc)
    return [word for word in without_punc.split() if not word in set(stopwords.words('english'))]

df['message'].head().apply(preprocess_text)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
x = df['message']
y = df['label']
cv = CountVectorizer()
x= cv.fit_transform(x)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=0)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
classifier = MultinomialNB().fit(x_train, y_train)

def sms(self):
    lab = ['not spam', 'spam']
    x = cv.transform([message]).toarray()
    p = classifier.predict(x)
    s = [str(i) for i in p]
    a = int("".join(s))

    # show out the final result
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result', methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = request.form['message']
        if not message == "":
            if sms(message):
                return render_template('index.html', result = 0, message = message)
            else:
                return render_template('index.html', result = 1, message = message)
        else:
            return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Full Error Traceback here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2548, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "W:\Desktop\sms-spam\app.py", line 82, in predict
    if sms(message):
  File "W:\Desktop\sms-spam\app.py", line 61, in sms
    x = cv.transform([message]).toarray()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1255, in transform
    _, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents, fixed_vocab=True)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1115, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 104, in _analyze
    doc = preprocessor(doc)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 69, in _preprocess
    doc = doc.lower()
AttributeError: module 'email.message' has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Post the full error traceback.

Comment: ... But please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're passing an email object to CountVectorizer() which first lowercases the text (see [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)) before tokenizing it.

To fix your error, you should pass the text/message and not the email object

Comment: this guy gets it! thanks for the community help

Comment: To convert an `email.message` object to string you can call the `as_string()` method of the `email.message` object.